# Create Child only and select a Parent in nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

Instead of creating a new Parent and also creating the children. Is it possible to select from a list of Parents and then only create the children that are assigned to a current user and that specific Survey?

Lets use this example:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
def new
  # @survey = select menu of all Surveys
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build
  end
end

def create
 # Saves new questions with current user
 if @survey.save
   flash[:notice] = "Success"
   redirect_to @survey
 else
   render :action => 'new'
 end
end
```

I'm not sure what the create and new actions would turn into. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the edit action on a existing survey passing the selected survey to it:

```
edit_survey_path(@survey)
```

Then you can load the selected survey in that action:

```
def edit
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the `edit` view, use a nested form to add/delete questions, and then, in the `update` action, updating your surveys attributes will also add and delete the questions.

```
def update
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
  redirect_to ...
end
```

All of this will work assuming you've set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` in the `survey` model.

My answer here is a summary of [Ryan Bates' screencast on nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) which I think you've already seen, based on the similarity of your example and his.

What I'd like to point out here is that you can achieve what you want using exactly the same code, however using the edit/update actions on your parent model instead of new/create on the child model.

**Edit:**

In order to assign the current user to a survey question, do the explicit assignment in the `new` and `edit` action:

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end
end

def edit
  # find the preselected Survey...
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])

  # This adds a (one) new empty question, consider doing it via Javascript
  # for adding multiple questions.
  @survey.questions.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

In your form for `questions`, add:

```
<%= form_builder.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

Don't forget to replace `form_builder` with your actual form builder object.

Now all the new questions will be assigned to the current user because the current user was submitted by the form along with the other attributes for `questions`.